# Eclipse add source files to package explorer

Tags: eclipse, maven

I checked out a Maven project folder from SVN. It is coming up as folders in the Package Explorer, and when I right click -> Build Path -> no actions available.

Is there anyway to add the source folder to appear as a package?

Answer (score 0):

The project is not set up as an Java or Maven project inside Eclipse. You can apply the Maven and Java nature afterwards in the project properties, you could run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` outside of Eclipse and import the created Eclipse project into your workspace (it could even exist as option in the project's context menu under "Maven", depending on how the project is setup right now).

Or, much easier, you just checkout a Maven project from SVN. Within the "New Project..." dialog there should be an option "Maven > Check Out Maven Projects from SVN". Then it will be configured automatically.